# Bash Script: Replace backslash characters in argument?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I have a script called test and I am trying to take in an argument and replace backslashes with forward slashes. If I do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

FIRST_ARGUMENT=$1

echo $FIRST_ARGUMENT | sed 's/\\/\//g'
```

And I use it in the following way:

```
$ ./test  aaa\aa    
aaaaa
```

My backslashes disappear. Is there a way to preserve them so they are replaced by sed? When I hardcode the path into a string within my echo call, as in:

```
echo 'aaa\aa'| sed 's/\\/\//g'
```

I get the proper result:

```
aaa/aa
```

Comment: the backslash is parsed away by the shell as it's processing the command line. You'd have to double-escape it for the escape to survive for use "inside" the command.

Comment: Use it as: `./test 'aaa\aa'`

Comment: also using lowercase for variable names is preferred, to avoid clashing with [shell variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Variables) which are all CAPS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While passing it to the `./test`, use quote `'` or `"` as:

```
./test 'aaa\aa'
```

Below is the example to show difference between content with quote and without quote:

```
moin@moin-pc:~$ echo aa\aa
aaaa  # without '\'
moin@moin-pc:~$ echo "aa\aa"
aa\aa  # with '\'
```

Also read: [Meaning of backslash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146665)